# Chrome dev tools performance screenshots stop recording after couple of minutes

Tags: performance, devtools

I face a problem chrome dev tools performance where the recording stops taking screenshots after a minute or so.
I have a recording of 7 minutes but it stopped taking screenshots after 1 minute. But the other performace aspects are working properly only the screenshots are stopping. After a certain point same screenshot repeats throughout the session.

I want continuous screen recording(screenshots) of the entire session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue and I suspect the answer is here in the Chromium code:

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/browser/devtools/devtools_traceable_screenshot.h

**Specifically, this line:**

```
static constexpr int kMaximumNumberOfScreenshots = 450;
```

So, it appears to be a hard limit - only 450 screenshots are captured in any trace.